# Keras Loss Function with Additional Dynamic Parameter

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm working on implementing prioritized experience replay for a deep-q network, and part of the specification is to multiply gradients by what's know as importance sampling (IS) weights.  The gradient modification is discussed in section 3.4 of the following paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.05952.pdf  I'm struggling with creating a custom loss function that takes in an array of IS weights in addition to `y_true` and `y_pred`.

Here's a simplified version of my model:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Input is RAM, each byte in the range of [0, 255].
in_obs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(4,))

# Normalize the observation to the range of [0, 1].
norm = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x / 255.0)(in_obs)

# Hidden layers.
dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")(norm)
dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")(dense1)
dense3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")(dense2)
dense4 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")(dense3)

# Output prediction, which is an action to take.
out_pred = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="linear")(dense4)

opt     = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=5e-5)
network = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=in_obs, outputs=out_pred)
network.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=huber_loss_mean_weighted)
```

Here's my custom loss function, which is just an implementation of Huber Loss multiplied by the IS weights:

```
'''
 ' Huber loss: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huber_loss
'''
def huber_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  error = y_true - y_pred
  cond  = tf.keras.backend.abs(error) < 1.0

  squared_loss = 0.5 * tf.keras.backend.square(error)
  linear_loss  = tf.keras.backend.abs(error) - 0.5

  return tf.where(cond, squared_loss, linear_loss)

'''
 ' Importance Sampling weighted huber loss.
'''
def huber_loss_mean_weighted(y_true, y_pred, is_weights):
  error = huber_loss(y_true, y_pred)

  return tf.keras.backend.mean(error * is_weights)
```

The important bit is that `is_weights` is dynamic, i.e. it's different each time `fit()` is called.  As such, I cannot simply close over `is_weights` as described here: [Make a custom loss function in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45961428/make-a-custom-loss-function-in-keras/45963039#45963039)

I found this code online, which appears to use a `Lambda` layer to compute the loss: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/image_ocr.py#L475  It looks promising, but I'm struggling to understand it/adapt it to my particular problem.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can `is_weights` be treated as an input variable to the network? If so, you can do it through `model.add_loss( huber_loss_mean_weightd( y_true, y_pred, is_weight) )`

Comment: @user36624 sure, `is_weights` can be treated as an input variable.  Using `add_loss` seems like a clean solution, but I cannot figure out how to use it.  For example, in your code snippet, where do `y_true` and `y_pred` come from?  Does `y_true` correspond to `out_pred` in my code?  And after I `add_loss`, what do I use as the `loss` parameter for compile?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

OK. Here is an example.

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Flatten
from keras.models import Model
from keras.losses import categorical_crossentropy

def sample_loss( y_true, y_pred, is_weight ) :
    return is_weight * categorical_crossentropy( y_true, y_pred ) 

x = Input(shape=(32,32,3), name='image_in')
y_true = Input( shape=(10,), name='y_true' )
is_weight = Input(shape=(1,), name='is_weight')
f = Conv2D(16,(3,3),padding='same')(x)
f = MaxPool2D((2,2),padding='same')(f)
f = Conv2D(32,(3,3),padding='same')(f)
f = MaxPool2D((2,2),padding='same')(f)
f = Conv2D(64,(3,3),padding='same')(f)
f = MaxPool2D((2,2),padding='same')(f)
f = Flatten()(f)
y_pred = Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='y_pred' )(f)
model = Model( inputs=[x, y_true, is_weight], outputs=y_pred, name='train_only' )
model.add_loss( sample_loss( y_true, y_pred, is_weight ) )
model.compile( loss=None, optimizer='sgd' )
print model.summary()
```

Note, since you've add loss through `add_loss()`, you don't have to do it through `compile( loss=xxx )`.

With regards to train a model, nothing is special except you move `y_true` to your input end. See below

```
import numpy as np 
a = np.random.randn(8,32,32,3)
a_true = np.random.randn(8,10)
a_is_weight = np.random.randint(0,2,size=(8,1))
model.fit( [a, a_true, a_is_weight] )
```

Finally, you can make a testing model (which share all weights in `model`) for easier use, i.e.

```
test_model = Model( inputs=x, outputs=y_pred, name='test_only' )
a_pred = test_model.predict( a )
```

Comment: That's awesome!  I really appreciate you taking the time to create an example.  I've been struggling with this for awhile now, and this solution is a lot cleaner than the OCR example I referenced in my question.  Thank you.

Comment: Is this method work when a train and a test input are get by generator function?

Comment: Yes. I think so.

Comment: @pitfall, is this the same for multiple loss functions.